# Julia: Passing Plot optional arguments through outer function

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I have a function in Julia that produces a plot using the `Plots` package `plot()` command. I'd like to set some optional arguments for the plot by passing arguments into my outer function. For example, I'd like to set title and axis labels without needing to program a bunch of `if` statements to check what parameters I'm trying to pass in. A MWE of what I'd like to do is as follows:

```
function outer(data; plot_options...)
   x = data.x
   y = data.y
   plot(x,y, plot_options...)
end
```

So that if I call something like `outer(data, title="My Title", lw=2)` I produce a plot with title set to "My Title" and a linewidth of 2. Trying the naive thing that I programmed above results in an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function outer(data; plot_options...)
   x = data.x
   y = data.y
   plot(x,y; plot_options...)
end
```

missed a semicolon?